# Existe manera de ponerle un máximo a una variable que es igual a 0

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando que esa variable que empieza por **0** vaya aumentando obviamente y su tope o máximo sea **100** todo esto con javascript.

```js
var total = 0; // EMPIEZA POR 0 Y QUIERO QUE SU MÁXIMO SEA 100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tan simple como hacer esto

```
var total = 0;
if (total >= 100) {
  // con esto verificamos que el valor de 'total' sea 100
  // y así evitamos que aumenté o pase de 100
  total = 100;
}
```

Te dejo un ejemplo

```js
  var total = 95; // supongamos que este es nuestro valor inicial
  var button = document.getElementById('increase');
  var span = document.querySelector('.total');
  button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (total >= 100) {
      total = 100;
      console.log('Ya no puedes aumentar mas el valor de "total"');
    } else {
      total++;
    }
    span.innerText = total;
  });
```

```html
  <button id="increase">Aumentar <span class="total"></span></button>
```

Comment: Debería comprobar por si es mayor, no por si es igual.

Comment: @ArtEze quizás ambas opciones serian buenas `>=`

Comment: Está genial pero veo mejor sustituir esto:

if (total >= 100) {
      total = 100;
      console.log('Ya no puedes aumentar mas el valor de "total"');
    } else {
      total++;
    }

Por esto:

total < 100 ? total++ : console.log("total ya es 100.");

Es una condición ternaria y al ser de una linea en cada caso de la condición (if y else) queda más limpia de esta forma y si lo quieres depurar más se podría hacer una función flecha de tal forma que el evento quedaría así:

button.addEventListener('click', () => total < 100 ? total++ : console.log("Máximo alcanzado"));